# Visibility parameters support And (&&) operator in fremarker android studio

Tags: android-studio, templates, plugins, freemarker

I am creating a template using freemarker. I want to check And (&&) operator with two checkbox. I check it with &&, it not working. The following is a sample template code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<template
    minApi="7"
    minBuildApi="8">

.......
<parameter 
   id="hasTabLayout" 
   name="Have Tab Layout" 
   type="boolean" 
   default="false"/>

<parameter 
   id="hasRecycleViewTabOne" 
   name="Tab one have recycleView" 
   type="boolean" 
   default="false"/>

<parameter
   id="adapterTabOneName"
   name="Adapter Tab One Name"
   type="string"
   constraints="class|unique|nonempty"
   default="BlankTabOneItem"
   **visibility="hasTabLayout && hasRecycleViewTabOne"** />
.......
```

Answer (score 1):

Note sure what error message you are getting, but `&&` is not well-formed XML. It should be `&amp;&amp;` instead.

Comment: It still not working. In android studio, My template not show if i use And(&&) Operator.

Comment: I assume you have replaced it with `&amp;&amp;`. Do you get any error message in some log at least?

Comment: Yes, when i use &amp;&amp; . My template not show and i don't get any error message.

Comment: I don't know the reason... but there should be a log somewhere.